# Interceptor Method Not Invoked

Tags: jsf, glassfish, cdi, interceptor

The container is  Glassfish. I have implemented an `@PostConstruct` life-cycle event interceptor method in a simple DAO bean class, but seems like for some reason it is not intercepting my business method at all. I do not anywhere manually instantiate the bean classes. `beans.xml` discovery mode is all and since I don't annotate `DefaultUserDao` bean, so it gets the default scope.

```
public class DefaultUserDao implements UserDao {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    Scanner users = null;
    String[] userNamePasswordPairs = null;

    public DefaultUserDao() {
        try {
            users = new Scanner(Paths.get("/home/NetBeansProjects/EJBInAction/web/users"));
        } 

        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DefaultUserDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    /*The interceptor for this method is defined right below, that 
      interceptor method is not called at all. If I insert a
      System.out.println(userNamePasswordPairs) after the split()
      method below, it prints [userName:password] pair twice and there
      is only one line in the text file from which the pair was read  in the
      form like this admin:admin. Notice that I also insert a System.out.println()
      method in the interceptor method but if I remove the print()
      method from this init() method, I don't see it prints anything
      */
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        while (users.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = users.nextLine();
            userNamePasswordPairs = line.split(":");
            //If I uncomment this, I see it prints [admin:admin] pair
            //twice, but when I comment it out, I don't see it prints  anything
           //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userNamePasswordPairs));
            userName = userNamePasswordPairs[0];
            password = userNamePasswordPairs[1];
        }
    }

    @AroundConstruct
    private void printUser(InvocationContext ic) {
        //If this interceptor was invoked, it should print at least "Interceptor invoked: "
        //But it does not print this.
        System.out.println("Interceptor invoked: " + Arrays.toString(userNamePasswordPairs));
        try {
            ic.proceed();
        } 

        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

A simple JSF page gathering username and password

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    @Inject
    private UserDao userDao;

    public LoginBean() {
    }

    public LoginBean(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String validateUser() {

        if (userDao.getUserName().equals(userName) && userDao.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        }
    
        else {
            userName = "Error";
            password = "Error";
        }
        return "confirmation.xhtml";
    }

    //getter and setter for userName and password

}
```

Comment: @PostContruct does not work on pojo's. Only on managed beans like jsf, cdi, ejb.

Comment: It is a bean. I am able to inject it into `LoginBean`

Comment: How?  Via an xml file? Not via annotations

Comment: Yeah. `beans.xml` discovery mode is all and since I don't annotate `DefaultUserDao`, so it gets the default scope

Comment: Please add all this to the question right before the code

Comment: Do not pollute your beans/services with cross-cutting concerns like interceptors. Take them out of your managed beans/services.

Comment: Yeah, I had an interceptor class before trying interceptor method. But polluted or not is not important in this context. What is annoying is the interceptor is not being invoked

Comment: Sorry for any confusion I only have Glassfish. I have tried both methods of creating interceptors -class and method. But my interceptor is still not invoked. The spec says that interceptors can be private but must not be static or final. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkedm.html `Lifecycle interceptor methods can have public, private, protected, or package-level access, and must not be declared static or final.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that `@PostContruct` is a lifecycle callback - and not an interceptor - while `@AroundConstruct` is an interceptor method. They have different meanings and are declared differently.

Also note that the invocation order is typically the following:

1. The constructor interceptor is called
2. The constructor is called through the `proceed()` method in the interceptor.
3. Injection is performed (basically `@Inject` fields/setters are set)
4. The `@PostConstruct` lifecycle callback is called.

---

Regarding the `@PostConstruct` lifecycle callback, you declare it correctly. And It seems to be called since it prints some text.

---

Regarding the interceptor, the following is missing:

- Your interceptor must be declared in a separate class, not in a bean.
- Your interceptor class must be declared in the `META-INF/beans.xml` file under the `<interceptors>` element **OR** it must be annotated with the `javax.annotations.Priority` annotation specifying a priority value. The later option makes your interceptor application-wide, basically: it will apply to the whole app instead of just the jar containing the `META-INF/beans.xml`. To start, I recommend you declare it in the `META-INF/beans.xml`.
- Your interceptor must be annotated with `@Interceptor` (`javax.interceptor.Interceptor`)
- You must declare an interceptor binding on your interceptor and declare the beans/methods you want to intercept with it.

To summarize, you have to create an interceptor binding for your interceptor:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Greet {

}
```

Then you have to create a class for your interceptor, using the interceptor binding:

```
@Greet
@Interceptor
public class GreetInterceptor {

    @AroundConstruct
    public void aroundConstruct(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello!!");
        ic.proceed();
    }
}
```

Then declare it in your `META-INF/beans.xml`:

```
<interceptors>
    <class>com.sandbox.GreetInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
```

Finally, annotate the bean you want to intercept calls with the interceptor binding:

```
@Greet
public class DefaultUserDao implements UserDao {
    ...
}
```